# Effect of disabling auto-index-creation but retaining @Indexed annotations

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3049 the automatic creation of indexes in Spring Data MongoDb is now deprecated and disabled by default. However, we would like to retain the `@Indexed` annotations in the code for documentation purposes only.

If we were to skip removing all the `@Indexed` and `@CompoundIndexes` annotations from our `@Document`-annotated classes (I.e. just leave them), meanwhile allowing the default disabled automatic index creation behavior (or explicitly setting `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation = false`) would this have the same effect as removing all the `@Indexed` and `@CompoundIndexes` annotations from the code entirely?

I'm concerned that leaving those annotations in the code might continue to have side affects and/or cause errors unrelated to automatic index creation. Or are these annotations exclusively to support automatic index creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following applies for Spring Boot `2.5.2` and Spring Data Mongo `3.2.2`.

TL;DR;

If `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=false` is set, no indices are created automatically and annotations like `@Indexed` will have no impact on your mongo collections. On the other hand, they will still allow gathering those index informations from the entity using `MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver` at runtime in a programmatic way.

Detailed walkthrough

When setting `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=false`

- the setting will propagate from `MongoProperties` via `MongoDataConfiguration` into the `MongoMappingContext` bean, where it's available as `MongoMappingContext#isAutoIndexCreation`
- this is then evaluated in the constructor of `MongoTemplate` (and `ReactiveMongoTemplate`) to determine, whether the newly created `(Reactive)MongoTemplate` should have an instance of `MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator` assigned or not
- if an instance of `MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator` is created during the construction of `MongoTemplate`, the index creation logic will kick-in on object creation (constructor) of `MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator`

References

- `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties#isAutoIndexCreation`
- `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataConfiguration#mongoMappingContext`
- `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext#isAutoIndexCreation`
- `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate#MongoTemplate`
- `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator#MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator`